# Are the meanings of "Car's broken door" & "Broken door of car" the same?

Tags: sentence-meaning, possessives

Are the meanings of these two phrases the same? If not, what is the difference?

> Car's broken door

vs

> Broken door of car

Comment: Similar question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/91519

Answer (score -1):

> #### Forming the Possessive
>
> The possessive form is used with nouns referring to people, groups of people, countries, and animals. It shows a relationship of belonging between one thing and another.
>
> […]
>
> To form the possessive, add apostrophe + s to the noun. If the noun is plural, or already ends with "s", just add an apostrophe after the "s".
>
> […]
>
> 'Belonging to' or 'ownership' is the most common relationship the possessive expresses.

<sup>([Forming the possessive | EF](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/forming-possessive/))</sup>

Examples:

- Apple’s taste
- Book’s cover
- Boss’s car

> #### Making singular nouns possessive
>
> Add an apostrophe + s to most singular nouns and to plural nouns that
>   do not end in s.
>
> English has some words that are plural but do not add an ‘s’. Words
>   like children, sheep, women and men are such words. These plural words
>   are treated as if they were singular words when making noun
>   possessives.
>
> Examples:
>
> Singular nouns: kitten’s toy, Joe’s car, MLB’s ruling
>
> Plurals not ending in s: women’s dresses, sheep’s pasture, children’s toys.
>
> #### Making plural nouns possessive
>
> Add an apostrophe only to plural nouns that already end in s.
>
> You don’t need to add an extra ‘s’ to plural nouns that already end
>   with the letter ‘s’. Simply tuck the apostrophe onto the end to
>   indicate that the plural noun is now a plural possessive noun.
>
> Examples:
>
> Companies’ workers, Horses’ stalls, Countries’ armies

[Your Dictionary](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/Possessive-Nouns.html#qJeWqAlUrGgHpocy.99)

**Your Question**

> Car's broken door
>
> vs
>
> Broken door of the car

Both can be used no difference in the meaning, you can write the two forms.

Comment: The answer contains verbatim text from an unattributed source.